# package from Bioconductor has a dependency from CRAN that requires version of R that is not compatible

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

A particular situation we've encountered is when we try to install a specific R package version from Bioconductor. Dependencies of this package may not be pinned, which means that the latest and greatest dependency will be installed from CRAN. The problem arises when this new latest and greatest dependency refers to an R version that is not compatible with the Bioconductor release in which the original package is being installed. At this point installation process tips over and crashes spectacularly.

For example, [DESeq2 ver. 1.30.1](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/bioc/html/DESeq2.html) is from the 3.12 relase of Bioconductor which in turn depends on R 4.0. DESeq2 Depends on unpinned version of [locfit](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/locfit/index.html) and latest version depends on R >= 4.1, making the installation process fail.

```
➜ docker run --rm -it r-base:4.0.4 bash --login
root@e2475c214bce:/# R

> install.packages("renv")
...
> renv::install("bioc::DESeq2@1.30.1")
...
Error: failed to retrieve package 'DESeq2@1.30.1'
In addition: Warning message:
In state$requirements[[record$Package]] :
  wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
Traceback (most recent calls last):
8: renv::install("bioc::DESeq2@1.30.1")
7: retrieve(names(remotes))
6: handler(package, renv_retrieve_impl(package))
5: renv_retrieve_impl(package)
4: renv_retrieve_bioconductor(record)
3: renv_retrieve_repos(record)
2: stopf("failed to retrieve package '%s'", renv_record_format_remote(record))
1: stop(sprintf(fmt, ...), call. = call.)
```

Let's ignore the fact that the error message from `renv` is not helpful and install `locfit` by hand.

```
> renv::install("locfit")
Error: package 'locfit' is not available
Error during wrapup: 
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Naturally this fails because the latest version of `locfit` depends on R>=4.1.

The solutions here are:

- pin dependencies in DESeq2, but this is unlikely to happen for older versions
- manually install compatible version of `locfit` that doesn't depend on R>=4.1 prior to installing DESeq2

Are there other ways of solving this that elude me?

Comment: Could you fork DESeq2 on [Github](https://github.com/mikelove/DESeq2), patch its DESCRIPTION file and use that instead of the Bioconductor version?

Comment: That's something I've thought of, but can get very unwieldy very fast if you want to install several packages.

Comment: I guess it would if this is a very common problem. Is this happening with multiple packages?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an overview of how many packages may be affected. The problem that I see with this approach is that one may need to pin dependencies of dependencies of dependencies... But, it would solve the problem...

Comment: If you are using R 4.0, then installing packages from CRAN that were available before 4.1.0 was released should be possible.  R 4.1.0 was released in May, 2021, so using the "CRAN Time Machine" mirror of CRAN as it was in April 2021 should get everything installed.  Then maybe `update.packages()` will work to get you newer versions for those that are compatible.

Comment: @user2554330 thanks. If I understand the problem correctly is that packages that I don't have (immediate) control over do not specify versions of their dependencies. And if that dependency has a different R version requirement than what is permissible within the Bioconductor release I'm using, the installation process breaks down.

Comment: Yes, I understood that.  That's why I'm not sure the `update.packages()` step will work.  But the initial install should.